# Sorting doesn't seem to work

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

This code is written in `C++`. I've the following structure:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Data
{
    int h, b, w;

    Data(int _h, int _b, int _w) : h(_h), b(_b), w(_w)
    {}

    bool operator<(const Data& other) const
    {
        bool overlap = (other.b >= b && other.b <= w) ||
            (other.w >= b && other.w <= w) ||
            (other.b < b && other.w > w);
        if (overlap)
        {
            return h < other.h;
        }

        return h > other.h;
    }
};
```

The `operator<` will be used for sorting. The idea is to sort from highest-h to lowest-h, unless there is any overlapping between either `b` or `w` in comparing variables. Remaining code:

```
vector <int> getOrdering(vector <int> height, vector <int> bloom, vector <int> wilt)
{
    vector<Data> vdata;

    for (int i = 0; i < height.size(); i++)
    {
        vdata.push_back(Data(height[i], bloom[i], wilt[i]));
    }

    sort(vdata.begin(), vdata.end());
    vector<int> ans;
    for (Data data : vdata)
    {
        ans.push_back(data.h);
    }

    return ans;
}

int main()
{
    vector <int> p0 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
    vector <int> p1 = { 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3 };
    vector <int> p2 = { 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4 };

    vector<int> ans = getOrdering(p0, p1, p2);

    for (int a : ans)
    {
        cout << a << ' ';
    }
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The way the I've written the `operator<` function, the code should output `2 4 6 1 3 5`. But the output is `6 5 4 3 2 1`. I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate.

After debugging the `operator<` function, I found out that it is being called for `Data` object as follows:

```
1st call: this->h = 2, other.h = 1
2nd call: this->h = 1, other.h = 2
3rd call: this->h = 3, other.h = 2
4th call: this->h = 2, other.h = 3
5th call: this->h = 4, other.h = 3
6th call: this->h = 3, other.h = 4
7th call: this->h = 5, other.h = 4
8th call: this->h = 4, other.h = 5
9th call: this->h = 6, other.h = 5
10th call: this->h = 5, other.h = 6
```

Note that when `Data` objects' h values are 1, 3 or 5, their b and w values are same. They will be sorted by ascending order of h. Same goes true for `Data` objects whose h values are 2, 4 and 6. But in the `operator<()` no two `Data` objects are ever compared whose h values are same! 1 compared to 2, 2 compared to 3, 3 compared to 4 and so on. So the `overlap` variable is always `false`. The outcome of `sort()` would be different if `Data` objects whose h values are same got compared - but that never happened!

Any explanation of this behavior of compiler?

Comment: Your `operator<` does not satisfy the requirements of strict weak ordering. For one thing, it's not transitive. Imagine three blocks, `A(h==20)`, `B(h==10)` and `C(h==30)`. `B` and `C` overlap, `A` doesn't overlap either. Then, according to your ordering, `A < B` and `B < C` but `!(A < C)`

Comment: Regardless: `overlap` can be calculated much easier: `bool overlap = other.b <= w && other.w >= b;` (assuming `b <= w`)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: Any link to guidance on it?

Comment: `The idea is to sort from highest-h to lowest-h, unless there is any overlapping` And if there is overlapping, then what? You need to figure out meaningful ordering for this case. I can't help you there, because I don't have any idea what real-world phenomena all those numbers are supposed to represent.

Comment: `the code should output 2 4 6 1 3 5` Why is that? The block `H5` with height of 5 doesn't overlap the block `H2` with height of 2, and its height is greater, so `H5` should precede `H2` in the sorted order, shouldn't it? How come you expect a result that doesn't match your own explanation? It appears that you yourself haven't yet figured out exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: I think I understand what the problem is. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because your operator< depends a lot of the data order. If we run you're algorithm with your data, it's the expected output.

The first comparaison is between Data(1,1,2) and Data(2,3,4). According to your operator<, Data(2,3,4) is the lower so the temp order is [Data(2,3,4), Data(1,1,2)]

Then, Data(3,1,2) comes and is compared against the lowest value of the current sorted list, so Data(2,3,4). Again, according to your operator<, Data(3,1,2) is lower so no need to compare against the other values in the list and the new temp ordered list is [Data(3,1,2),Data(2,3,4), Data(1,1,2)].

Then it's the same for each other value, they are each time only compared to the first value in the list since they are lower (according to operator<) and so put in front of the sorted list.

If you change your init list order with:

```
vector <int> p0 = { 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1};
vector <int> p1 = { 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1};
vector <int> p2 = { 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2};
```

you'll have the expected output since there will be more comparaison involved.

But the fact that the result depend on the init order show there is clearly a flaw in your operator< function.